# Display modal window only once with React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-hooks

I'm using a custom hook to display modal window, do you know how can I display the modal window once, right now when I refresh the window I can see again the modal window...

What approach will be the best?

This is my code:

```
import React from "react";
import useModal from "./customHooks/useModal";
import Modal from "./customHooks/Modal";

const SearchPage = ({ location }) => {
  const { isShowing, toggle } = useModal();

  const search = window.location.search;
  const parametros = "?q=Search";

  window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {

      console.log('Event', event);
    });

  return (
    <>
      <p>
        <strong>Location Props: </strong>
        {location.search}
      </p>

      {parametros === search ? (
        <Modal
          width={["333px", "111px"]}
          height={["555px", "444px"]}
          margin={["0px 10px 3px 5px", "1px 2px 3px 4px"]}
          padding={["0px 11px 4px 7px", "1px 2px 3px 4px"]}
          isShowing={!isShowing}
          hide={toggle}
          contentModal={"OK Modal"}
        />
      ) : (
        <Modal
          width={["333px", "111px"]}
          height={["555px", "444px"]}
          margin={["0px 10px 3px 5px", "1px 2px 3px 4px"]}
          padding={["0px 11px 4px 7px", "1px 2px 3px 4px"]}
          isShowing={!isShowing}
          hide={toggle}
          contentModal={"Error Modal"}
        />
      )}

      <button className="button-default" onClick={toggle}>
        Show Modal
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchPage;
```

Thank you and Regards,

Comment: you can save modal status in local storage then load it when component mount

Comment: Can you provide a quick example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage a state with localStorage.

When a modal activate, set a value to localStorage.

+)

```
const SearchPage = ({ location }) => {
  const { isShowing, toggle } = useModal();
  console.log("LOCATION", location);
  const search = window.location.search;
  console.log("SEARCH", search);
  const params = new URLSearchParams(search);
  console.log("PARAMS", params);
  const foo = params.get("bar");
  console.log("foo", foo);

  const parametros = "?q=Search";

  window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {

      console.log('Event', event);
    });

  // create a click method check if a value in localStorage
  const handleClick = () => {
    const flag = localStorage.getItem('flag');
    if (!flag) {
      localStorage.setItem('flag', true);
      toggle();
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <p>
        <strong>Location Props: </strong>
        {location.search}
      </p>

      {parametros === search ? (
        <Modal
          width={["333px", "111px"]}
          height={["555px", "444px"]}
          margin={["0px 10px 3px 5px", "1px 2px 3px 4px"]}
          padding={["0px 11px 4px 7px", "1px 2px 3px 4px"]}
          isShowing={!isShowing}
          hide={toggle}
          contentModal={"OK Modal"}
        />
      ) : (
        <Modal
          width={["333px", "111px"]}
          height={["555px", "444px"]}
          margin={["0px 10px 3px 5px", "1px 2px 3px 4px"]}
          padding={["0px 11px 4px 7px", "1px 2px 3px 4px"]}
          isShowing={!isShowing}
          hide={toggle}
          contentModal={"Error Modal"}
        />
      )}
      // change toggle function to we created handleClick functtion as above.
      <button className="button-default" onClick={handleClick}>
        Show Modal
      </button>
    </>
  );
};

export default SearchPage;
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?